# Using sed to fill blanks with 0's (zero's)

Tags: linux, sed

Does anyone know of a way to replace blanks with 0's? Here's what im trying to do...
Basically i have a script that pulls an ip address and manipulates the address to make a port number out of it.

```
192.168.202.3 = Port 23
```

what i need is a smart enough sed command to add 2 0's in front of the 3 making it a full value.

```
192.168.202.3 = Port 2003
```

or:

```
192.168.202.003 = Port 2003
```

The catch is, if the number already exists then i dont want it to add 0's..

```
192.168.202.254 = Port 2254
```

instead of:

```
192.168.202.254 = Port 200254
```

Any ideas on how to do it?

Relevant Portion of the script:

```
# Retrieve local-ipv4 address from meta-data
GET http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4 > /metadata

# Create a manipulated version of ipv4 to use as a port number
sed "s/192.168.20//" /metadata > /metaport
sed -i "s/\.//g" /metaport
```

If you have another way without using sed im open for those suggestions as well!!

Thanks!

Comment: Your 'full' value is not a valid IP. And what do you mean by 'manipulates the address to make a port number out of it'? How is a port derived from an IP?

Comment: Im using sed to do so... here's the script:
# Retrieve local-ipv4 address from meta-data
GET http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4 > /metadata

# Create a manipulated version of ipv4 to use as a port number
sed "s/192.168.20//" /metadata > /metaport
sed -i "s/\.//g" /metaport

Comment: How? Please edit your question to include what you have tried. And please also describe what you want to achive. I don't understand your question.

Comment: So in a nutshell, it calls the metadata and pulls an actual IP. Then sed removes 192.168.20 from the IP leaving 1.xxx. Then next line removes the "." leaving 1xxx. Problem is if xxx = 4 then i need sed to make it 004

Comment: And indicate if you really must use `sed`, or if you are open to other solutions to this problem. While its possible to solve the Tower's of Hanoi puzzle with sed, its not something I would want anyone to maintain after I had installed it AND while it **may** be possible to solve your problem with `sed` it will be a masters-class solution, worthy of hefty consulting fees ;-) Good luck!

Comment: Yes, Im open to any bash suggestion to complete this task!! sed was just what came to mind cause it seems to be the most versatile

Comment: @NickHatfield `awk` can handle this better way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would prefer using `awk` for number manipulation rather than `sed`

```
awk -F'.' '{printf "%03s%03s\n", $3, $4}' /metadata | cut -c3-6 > /metaport
```

Input IP:

```
192.168.202.3
192.168.202.23
192.168.202.254
```

Output Port:

```
2003
3023
2254
```

**EDIT**

More concise `awk` only solution avoiding need of `cut` (Suggested by [Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler))

```
awk -F'.' '{printf "%d%03d\n", $3 % 10, $4}' /metadata > /metaport
```

Comment: Sorry, I clicked the wrong one... this is the one i used for the solution!!! My apologies!!

Comment: Beware if the IP address is ever 192.168.10.3 or other variations where there are not 3 digits in the third part of the IP address.  You could make it safe for that by using `"%03s%03s\n"` for the format string, but surely you can also avoid the need for `cut` with `{printf "%d%03d\n", $3 % 10, $4}`, or other variations.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks a lot for your feedback. I have edited ans with your suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

If the input file contains only an IP address, then brute force and ignorance can do the job:

```
sed -e 's/\([0-9]\)\.\([0-9]\)$/& = Port \100\2/' \
    -e 's/\([0-9]\)\.\([0-9][0-9]\)$/& = Port \10\2/' \
    -e 's/\([0-9]\)\.\([0-9][0-9][0-9]\)$/& = Port \1\2/'
```

The first expression deals with 1 digit; the second with 2 digits; the third with 3.

Given input data:

```
192.168.202.3
192.168.203.13
192.168.202.003
192.168.202.254
```

the output is:

```
192.168.202.3 = Port 2003
192.168.203.13 = Port 3013
192.168.202.003 = Port 2003
192.168.202.254 = Port 2254
```

If you have a different input data format, you have to work harder to isolate the relevant section of the IP address, but you should really, really show what the input data looks like.

Comment: All of you are rockstars!! Thank you!! This got the job done precisely how i needed it done!!!

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, bash:

```
while IFS=. read a b c d; do
    printf "%d%03d\n" $((c%10)) $d
done <<END
192.168.202.3
192.168.202.003
192.168.209.123
127.0.0.1
END
```

```
2003
2003
9123
0001
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the description -- only insert two zeros when we only have 2 digits into the port the following should work:

```
sed -r '/Port [0123456789]{2}$/s/Port (.)/\100/'
```

So this only matches when Port is followed by 2 digits. If it does match, replace the first digit with that digit and two zeros.

If you need to handle 3 digits, another match section that does just 3 digits could be trivially added.

Comment: Very helpful!!! You guys rock!! This got me close but the one below did the trick 100% Thank you VERY MUCH!!! Incredible support on this site!!!